# How does D3.js draw irregular axes?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The expected effect is as follows:
[image]

But this effect cannot be achieved through d3.scaleLinear()

Comment: Well, no, since this is a logarithmic scale. It is achieved with `d3.scaleLog()`